# How do I set the height of an element to match the offset speed of a scaling div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I am trying to set the maximum scroll of an element, in this case `.contain`, to match the height needed for `.square` to fill the entire viewport (both width and height) on scroll. I need to figure out how I can retrieve the remaining height needed to cover the offset value of the scroll.

Here is a codepen showing what currently happens. The scroll reaches the bottom and the square fails to fill the screen. Without the offset I can get this to work perfectly (see line 17), but I'd really like to learn how I can incorporate the parallax offset/speed effect.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbeyQd

---

The non-offset version to show how the above pen should work. Square fills the screen as the scrollbar hits the bottom: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Rdvvom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```js
const sq = document.querySelector('.square')
const contain = document.querySelector('.contain')

//set desired scroll boundaries. can be any size
//the higher the value the longer you'll have to scroll
const scrollOffset = 250
const sqW = sq.offsetWidth
const sqH = sq.offsetHeight
const wHeight = window.innerHeight
const wWidth = window.innerWidth

contain.style.height = `${wHeight + scrollOffset}px`

window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  const percentScroll = window.scrollY * 100 / scrollOffset
  const width = (wWidth - sqW) * percentScroll / 100
  const height = (wHeight - sqH) * percentScroll / 100
  sq.style.width = `${sqW + width}px`
  sq.style.height = `${sqH + height}px`
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.contain {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: papayawhip;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
    
  <div class="square"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks @iacobalin , is there anyway to keep the square a square and increase with equal height/width on scroll?

Comment: Ah! Actually I think I just find the largest axis and then swap which value I use. Either width or height to match the browser orientation? I think you might be a genius!

Comment: Is there anyway I could get this to work with a circle?